# Let $f(x)$ be the $2π$-periodic function defined by $ f(x)= \begin{cases} 1+x&\,x \in \mathbb [0,π)\\ -x-2&\, x \in \mathbb [-π,0)\\ \end{cases} $

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, absolute-convergence, pointwise-convergence, conditional-convergence

Let $f(x)$ be the $2π$-periodic function defined by

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1+x&\,x \in \mathbb [0,π)\\
 -x-2&\, x \in \mathbb [-π,0)\\
\end{cases}
$ 
Then the Fourier series of  $f$

$(A)$ converges to $-1/2$ in $x=0$
$(B)$ does not converge pointwise in all points where $f$ is discontinuous
$(C)$ does not converge in $x=π/2$
$(D)$ converges to $1$ in $x=0$

Picture of actual question is [Link to the Real Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajCsx.png)

Correct answer is 'A' but I am unable to get it.
I have tried calculating the Fourier series and then calculate for its convergence. The calculations are difficult to be shown here as I am not acquainted with the Math Latex. Please help me solve the question

Answer (score 0):

A basic fact about the Fourier series of a $2\pi$-periodic piecewise $C^1$ function $f$ is that it converges pointwise to $$f_*(x):=\frac{f(x^-) + f(x^+)}{2},$$
where $f(x^\pm) = \lim_{t \to x^\pm} f(t)$ are the left- and right-hand limit of $f$ at $x$; this holds *for all* $x$ in the domain of $f$, even where $f$ is not continuous. Where $f$ is continuous, $f_* = f$ (and the convergence is uniform).

Answer (score 0):

The word "at" is more appropriate than "in" here.

For a piecewise continuous function, at points of discontinuity, the Fourier series converges to the midpoint of the limits of each piece.

The first piece has $\lim_ {x\downarrow 0}  f(x) = f(0)=1$ and the second piece has $\lim_ {x\uparrow 0} f(x) =-2.$

The midpoint is $\frac{(1-2)}{2} = - \frac{1}{2}.$

So yes, choice (A) is correct.